GEE giving error "empty image collection" for a single date, whereas image for the roi exists in copernicus browser
I want to export surface reflectance bands of Sentinel-2 MSI for my region of interest for a single date. I used the following code:
var dateOfInterest = '2024-11-04';
var s2Collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filterDate(dateOfInterest, dateOfInterest);
                  .first();

This throws the error "Error: Collection.first: Empty date ranges not supported for the current operation".
I have checked Copernicus Browser for availability of SR_L2A product for my ROI for a single date. I am not understanding why Google Earth Engine is giving this error. I do not want a median or composite image. I want to export all the bands individually for one single date of the surface reflectance (L2A) product.
Can someone kindly help me regarding this? Any help is appreciated. Many thanks!
